# Polylang Pro Wordpress plugin file not found error on live server

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, custom-wordpress-pages, polylang

I am working on a Wordpress website that uses the Polylang Pro plugin and has a file called polylang-custom-string-translations.php which has the following code:

```
pll_register_string('info', 'Info');
```

The above code is just one example it has a lot of translations like this.

The problem is the website is working fine on localhost but when I moved it to a subdomain on a live server the website gives the following error:

[Error that appears when I visit the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTdqL.png)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? I uploaded the website from localhost to liverserver using FTP and then imported the database and changed the links in the database as well using the query below:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldurl.com','newurl.com');UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com'); UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldurl.com','newurl.com');
```

Comment: It look like you haven't uploaded vendor folder properly. Try to upload vendor folder again. If you run 'Composer update' on local machine before uploading that will be plus.

Comment: I re-uploaded the vendor folder changed some things and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to upload the vendor folder of the plugin again, since I was using FTP it might have disconnected. So, I uploaded the vendor folder again and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).